# Injecting SecurityContextHolder via Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-aop

I want to log information of my requests by using Spring-AOP. Afterwards I want to cover this scenario with tests. Normally i would use the `SecurityContextHolder` simply but since i dont have the spring context in my Unit-Test I need to mock this element somehow. Since i want to avoid mocking private methods I therefore passed the `SecurityContextHolder` via `Autowired` annotation, I was exptecing this to be a Singleton anyways somehow.

```
@PrepareForTest(SecurityContextHolder.class)
public class AuditLoggerTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

  @Mock
  AuditLogPersistenceService persistenceService;

  @Mock
  SecurityContextHolder securityContextHolder;

  @Mock
  SecurityContext securityContext;

  @Mock
  Authentication authentication;

  AuditLogger auditLogger;

  @BeforeClass
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUpBeforeEachTest(){
    auditLogger = new AuditLogger(persistenceService, securityContextHolder);
    Object principal = new String("123");
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    when(securityContextHolder.getContext()).thenReturn(securityContext);
    when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
  }
```

Now the initilization of my class looks like this

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuditLogger {

  private final AuditLogPersistenceService auditLogPersistenceService;

  private final SecurityContextHolder securityContextHolder;

  /**
   * Common constructor raising its beans
   * @param auditLogPersistenceService
   */
  @Autowired
  public AuditLogger(
      final AuditLogPersistenceService auditLogPersistenceService,
      final SecurityContextHolder securityContextHolder) {
    this.securityContextHolder = securityContextHolder;
    this.auditLogPersistenceService = auditLogPersistenceService;
  }
```

It works fine on Unit tests but once I turn on the Spring context in my functional tests which actually do REST request via restassured. I get this error message.

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.service.audit.logging.AuditLogger required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder' in your configuration.
```

So can I Autowire the SecurityContextHolder or do I have to use the Static implementation ?

Comment: you could autowire that, but this doesn't sound like the way to go. Also, a security context is definitely not a Singleton. Usually, you would inject the request context and access the security context out of the request (a security context is usually request-scoped). You would set that context in your request after authentication and creation of the security context. You could implement a provider mechanism for this that will be able to inject a request-scoped security context for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion the most simple way is to inject a mocked Context into the `SecurityContextHolder` which is like this. Then the SecurityContextHolder is not in the constructor anymore

```
public class AuditLoggerTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

      @Mock
      AuditLogPersistenceService persistenceService;

      @Mock
      SecurityContext securityContext;

      @Mock
      Authentication authentication;


      AuditLogger auditLogger;


      @BeforeClass
      public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      }

      @BeforeMethod
      public void setUpBeforeTest(){
        auditLogger = new AuditLogger(persistenceService);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        Object principal = new String("123");
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal);
      }
```